# How to set focus mode in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, focus, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturedevice

Actually the question is in the title of the question.

In [AVCaptureDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/focusMode) there is a property - Focus Mode.
There is no such thing in [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).

So the question is how can I manage focus settings in UIImagePickerController?

Answer (score 0):

You can set manual focus by tapping on the screen like in standard camera app. 
Any other focus settings, which Camera app doesn't have, are not available (at least in legal way).